# al conceder todos los privilegios a mi usuario de phpmyadmin en cpanel no le agrega el privilegio INSERT

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin, cpanel, godaddy

al conceder todos los privilegios a mi usuario de phpmyadmin en cpanel no le agrega el privilegio INSERT, y cuando lo quiero insertar privilegios a una base de datos en phpmyadmin me dice sin privilegios y #1045 - Acceso negado para usuario: 'root'@'localhost' (Usando clave: NO) como puedo solucionar esto? les agradecería su ayuda amigos llevo semanas intentando resolver esto pero en ningun lado saben como solucionar esto.

Comment: si hablas de cpanel, creo que afuerzas te pide la contraseña, o que le crees una. te recomiendo que descargues la base de datos, la elimines de cpanel y la vuelvas a motar al cpanel. ya creando un nuevo nombre y contraseña con todos los privilegios.

Answer (score 0):

> Acceso negado para usuario: 'root'@'localhost' (Usando clave: NO)

Es posible que puedas acceder del siguiente modo desde la consola:

```
sudo mysql
```

Si tienes acceso como root desde la consola deberías poder hacer esto mediante el siguiente comando.

```
GRANT INSERT PRIVILEGES ON nombredb.tabla TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';
```

donde nombredb es el nombre de la base de datos y tabla la tabla deseada.
También es posible utilizar asterisco para asignarle todas las tablas de la base de datos o todas las bases de datos.

A su vez es necesario refrescar los permisos mediante `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

Te agrego un [enlace](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/crear-un-nuevo-usuario-y-otorgarle-permisos-en-mysql-es) que te puede ser de ayuda.